# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'warnings'

Tags: numpy

[image]

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer
pt = PowerTransformer(method='yeo-johnson',standardize=True)

X_train['feature']=pt.fit_transform(np.array(X_train['feature']).reshape(-1, 1))

#fit the model only on the train set and transform the test set
X_test['feature']=pt.transform(np.array(X_test['feature']).reshape(-1, 1))
```

getting below error

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'warnings'

Comment: Please post the *full* stack trace as text, not an image of text.

Comment: See https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/23654

Answer (score 2):

working fine with numpy==1.23.4

giving error with numpy==1.24.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Anyone coming here can run: pip install numpy==1.23.4
until the latest is fixed.

Comment: I don't think it's going to be fixed. `numpy.warnings` was just an alias for the builtin `warnings` and it's been removed from the `numpy` namespace. Turns out we should have just been using the builtin all along! https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/118e6c433a9afdefbfad7652f56e2b97e23bc508

Comment: Anyone coming here can add `import numpy, warnings` and `numpy.warnings = warnings` to the top of their main script. As a workaround of course.