# Module 'numpy' has no attribute 'warnings'

Tags: python, numpy, datashader

I'm trying to reproduce [this](https://datashader.org/user_guide/Polygons.html#geopandas-import) tutorial with my own data. I've a simple square grid of polygons:

```
from shapely import wkt
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

data_list = [
    [0,51, wkt.loads("POLYGON ((-74816.7238 5017078.8988, -74716.7238 5017078.8988, -74716.7238 5016978.8988, -74816.7238 5016978.8988, -74816.7238 5017078.8988))")],
    [1,91, wkt.loads("POLYGON ((-74816.7238 5016978.8988, -74716.7238 5016978.8988, -74716.7238 5016878.8988, -74816.7238 5016878.8988, -74816.7238 5016978.8988))")],
    [2,88, wkt.loads("POLYGON ((-74816.7238 5016878.8988, -74716.7238 5016878.8988, -74716.7238 5016778.8988, -74816.7238 5016778.8988, -74816.7238 5016878.8988))")],
    [3,54, wkt.loads("POLYGON ((-74816.7238 5016778.8988, -74716.7238 5016778.8988, -74716.7238 5016678.8988, -74816.7238 5016678.8988, -74816.7238 5016778.8988))")],
    [4,51, wkt.loads("POLYGON ((-74816.7238 5016678.8988, -74716.7238 5016678.8988, -74716.7238 5016578.8988, -74816.7238 5016578.8988, -74816.7238 5016678.8988))")],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data_list, columns=["id", "data", "geometry"])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry="geometry", crs=32633)
```

I've translate GeoPandas GeoDataFrame to SpatialPandas Geodataframe:

```
from spatialpandas import GeoDataFrame

sp_gdf = GeoDataFrame(gdf)
```

At this point I try to create a choropleth map according to [this](https://datashader.org/user_guide/Polygons.html#plotting-as-filled-polygons) example:

```
import datashader as ds

canvas = ds.Canvas(plot_width=1000, plot_height=1000)
agg = canvas.polygons(sp_gdf, 'geometry', agg=ds.mean('data'))
```

But I'm facing in the error below:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[7], line 4
      1 import datashader as ds
      3 canvas = ds.Canvas(plot_width=1000, plot_height=1000)
----> 4 agg = canvas.polygons(sp_gdf, 'geometry', agg=ds.mean('data'))
      6 agg

File ~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/drakonotebook-larABRfp-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datashader/core.py:753, in Canvas.polygons(self, source, geometry, agg)
    751     agg = any_rdn()
    752 glyph = PolygonGeom(geometry)
--> 753 return bypixel(source, self, glyph, agg)

File ~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/drakonotebook-larABRfp-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/datashader/core.py:1258, in bypixel(source, canvas, glyph, agg, antialias)
   1255 canvas.validate()
   1257 # All-NaN objects (e.g. chunks of arrays with no data) are valid in Datashader
-> 1258 with np.warnings.catch_warnings():
   1259     np.warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', r'All-NaN (slice|axis) encountered')
   1260     return bypixel.pipeline(source, schema, canvas, glyph, agg, antialias=antialias)

File ~/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/drakonotebook-larABRfp-py3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:320, in __getattr__(attr)
    317     from .testing import Tester
    318     return Tester
--> 320 raise AttributeError("module {!r} has no attribute "
    321                      "{!r}".format(__name__, attr))

AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'warnings'
```

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04, with Python 3.10 and the code above runs in a Jupyter Notebook. Below the version of libraries in use:

- shapely: 2.0.1
- pandas: 2.0.1
- geopandas: 0.12.2
- spatialpandas: 0.4.7
- datashader: 0.14.4
- numpy: 1.24.3

Moreover the python environment is managed by Poetry 1.4.2

NB: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74863592/attributeerror-module-numpy-has-no-attribute-warnings) thread is complete unuseful.

Comment: This is pretty strange... This is what I see when I look for `numpy.warnings`:  `>>> np.warnings`  --> `<module 'warnings' from 'D:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\warnings.py'>`. 
`>>> np.__version__` --> `'1.21.5'`. But look, it looks like `warnings` is a module that is independent from Numpy and is just pointed to by numpy. Maybe try to look for and install a module called `warnings` using PIP?

Comment: It looks like `warnings` is a package built-in in Python

Comment: As a workaround,  you can try `import numpy, warnings` and  then `numpy.warnings = warnings`, as the first two lines of your script

Comment: It run now, thank you! Can you add your comment as answer?

Comment: See https://github.com/holoviz/datashader/issues/1209

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that `numpy.warnings` is just a reference to the `warnings` built-in Python module, as I can see on my NumPy version:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.21.5'
>>> np.warnings
<module 'warnings' from 'D:\\Anaconda3\\lib\\warnings.py'>
```

So, one possible **workaround** for your problem, may be adding that reference to the NumPy module in your script, manually, at runtime:

```
import numpy as np
import warnings
np.warnings = warnings

<YOUR SCRIPT HERE>
```

However, as described in the [thread](https://github.com/holoviz/datashader/issues/1209) pointed by user @WarrenWeckesser, you may want to update the version of the `datashader` package, so that package will no longer try to access the `np.warnings` reference, which turns out to have been [removed from numpy](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/23654).